# How to share dotenv bettween users?

Tags: python, dotenv

I have a running flask server as root and need a restricted user logged to the linux server with ssh in order to run a script.
Both need to read and write on the dotenv file.
I noticed that root overwrites the permissions every time he writes to the dotenv file.

I have the following permissions:

Before root write:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 343 Mar 26 02:50 /var/www/flask/.env`

After root write:

`-rw------- 1 root root 343 Mar 26 07:50 /var/www/flask/.env`

Now the restricted the user no longer has access to the dotenv file.

I thought the problem came from the fact that I was using `sudo apt install python3-dotenv`, but after uninstalling it and use only `pip3 install python-dotenv`, the problem persists.

what would be the best solution to share access to that dotenv file?

Comment: this issue was from dotenv installed from `pip3`, reinstalling dotenv from `pip` solved this, so my workround (`sudo <COMMAND> && sudo chmod 755`) is no more necessary.

Comment: it's look like my workaround is still necessary if root is not the owner of the file e.g when using 2 dotenv files.